# Compare a user inputted value to an iterated value in a list

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension, typeerror

I am trying to compare values in a list of files (named as a date) to a user inputted start and end date, but I'm having some trouble when iterating the through the list in comparing the values.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import datetime
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
x = askdirectory()
start = input('Enter start date (ddmmyyyy): ')
    end = input('Enter end date (ddmmyyyy): ')
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%d%m%Y").strftime("%Y%m%d")
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%d%m%Y").strftime("%Y%m%d")
    start = int(start)
    end = int(end)

for files in os.walk(x):
        file = files[2]
        if '2' in file[1]:
            file = [int(i) for i in file]
            print(len(file))
            for i in file:
                if start >= file >= end:
                    fr.file_reader(time,rdata,intensity,files[i])
                    print(files[i])
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

I have tried converting the input to an integer, tried converting the list itself to integers but that didn't help. I know that at the moment it is reading the file as the whole list in the if loop, I just want it to read the ith file and iterate through, in order to read that file using my working file reader program. I can't work out how to achieve this.

Here is an what the first 10 files in my file list looks like. It's full length is 312 items so I won't copy it all here.

```
['20151123000103', '20151123220540', '20151124000043', '20151124003712', '20151125000055', '20151125070850', '20151126000101', '20151126000204', '20151126000330', '20151126000513']
```

If I could get any help with this I'd be most grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it, the error itself was fixed by replacing "file" with "i". Knew it would be something small and simple.